# Error trying to use react state in SPFX webpart

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I'm trying to create a webpart with React 17.01.  Previously I was setting the State in the constructor.  However, that is no longer allowed so I'm trying to use the React.useState() method. I'm not sure where I should be calling React.useState(). I am trying to store and display "nameOnCard". I made the following changes and I do not get an error when I serve.  However, when I add the webpart to the workbench I get the "something went wrong" message.  Below is my tsx file.  If anyone can help that would be great:

```html
import * as React from 'react';
//import {useState} from 'react';
import styles from './PaymentForm.module.scss';
import type { IPaymentFormProps } from './IPaymentFormProps';
//import { IPayment } from './IPayment';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

const[nameOnCard,setNameOnCard] = React.useState("");
export default class PaymentForm extends React.Component<IPaymentFormProps, {}> {
 
  constructor(props: IPaymentFormProps) {
    super(props);
    setNameOnCard("james");
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IPaymentFormProps> {
    
    const {
      description,
      isDarkTheme,
      environmentMessage,
      hasTeamsContext,
      userDisplayName
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <section className={`${styles.paymentForm} ${hasTeamsContext ? styles.teams : ''}`}>

        {nameOnCard}
        <div className={styles.welcome}>
          <img alt="" src={isDarkTheme ? require('../assets/welcome-dark.png') : require('../assets/welcome-light.png')} className={styles.welcomeImage} />
          <h2>Well done, {escape(userDisplayName)}!</h2>
          <div>{environmentMessage}</div>
          <div>Web part property value: <strong>{escape(description)}</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Welcome to SharePoint Framework!</h3>
          <p>
            The SharePoint Framework (SPFx) is a extensibility model for Microsoft Viva, Microsoft Teams and SharePoint. It&#39;s the easiest way to extend Microsoft 365 with automatic Single Sign On, automatic hosting and industry standard tooling.
          </p>
          <h4>Learn more about SPFx development:</h4>
          <ul className={styles.links}>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">SharePoint Framework Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-graph" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Use Microsoft Graph in your solution</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-teams" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Build for Microsoft Teams using SharePoint Framework</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-viva" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Build for Microsoft Viva Connections using SharePoint Framework</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-store" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Publish SharePoint Framework applications to the marketplace</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-api" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">SharePoint Framework API reference</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/m365pnp" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Microsoft 365 Developer Community</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SPFX now supports React hooks.  In order to get the hooks to work you need to modify the *.tsx file that Yoeman creates from a a default class to a React FunctionComponent. See full example at https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?q=react+hooks+in+spfx&mid=94A52363945C2236AB6294A52363945C2236AB62&FORM=VIRE:

[image]